# sql - searching query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently having a logical error in my sql query. I would like to display the records when I'm searching for the LastName and the FirstName of the record between the years.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    tablename
WHERE
    LastName LIKE 'value%'
        AND FirstName LIKE 'value%'
        AND Year BETWEEN '1900' AND '2017'
```

How do I do this?

Comment: *"How do I do this?"* - Aren't you doing it now? what's not working here? You may also need to use brackets for this.

Comment: seeing `value` looks more like a "write it for me" and "guess what my db schema looks like" kind of question

Comment: What does not work? The query looks fine. Are you getting rows you shouldn't get? Are you not getting rows you should get? Show examples.

Comment: what datatype are you using to store year?

Comment: You aren't searching for the same value for both LastName and FirstName, are you?  If you are, perhaps you meant to use "OR"?

Comment: @David maybe everyone is named David Davidson, John Johnson or Ziggy Zigster

Comment: @Plutonix Yeah--it's hard to know with such minimal information.  As Thorsten Kettner pointed out, we don't even know what the problem is...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your Year column is stored as an integer.  If so, remove the quotes around the year values 1900 and 2017 and the query should work as you expect.

Comment: what difference would removing the quotes do? MySQL will compensate for that

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, but why not do it right in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SQL, try this :

1- when year is stored as int

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
 tablename
  WHERE
   LastName LIKE 'value%'
    AND FirstName LIKE 'value%'
    AND columnx >= 1900 AND columnx <= 2017
```

2- when date stored like `01-01-1999` then use the following

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
 tablename
  WHERE
   LastName LIKE 'value%'
    AND FirstName LIKE 'value%'
    AND year(columnx) >= 1900 AND year(columnx) <= 2017
```